# How to fix sortables lists in top?

Tags: html, css

I need the lists to be "fixed" (but still sortable) at the top when there are more elements in one list than another, currently I get the opposite.

See the image below as what is happening:

[image]

The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.12.0/css/tachyons.min.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.scrollmenu {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dib {display: inline-block;}
.list-group-item{cursor: pointer;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <div class="list bg-light-gray dib" id="list1">
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list bg-light-gray dib" id="list2">
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list bg-light-gray dib" id="list3">
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script> 
<script>
  const sortables = [
      new Sortable(document.getElementById('list1'), {
      group: 'shared',
      animation: 150
      }),
      new Sortable(document.getElementById('list2'), {
      group: 'shared',
      animation: 150
      }),
      new Sortable(document.getElementById('list3'), {
      group: 'shared',
      animation: 150
      })];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to "fix" the sortables lists in top, of way that the spaces to be in bottom and not in top of the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vertical-align:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.12.0/css/tachyons.min.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.scrollmenu {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dib {display: inline-block;}
.list-group-item{cursor: pointer;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <div class="list bg-light-gray dib" id="list1" style="vertical-align: top;">
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list bg-light-gray dib" id="list2" style="vertical-align: top;">
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list bg-light-gray dib" id="list3" style="vertical-align: top;">
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script         src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js">    </script> 
<script>
  const sortables = [
      new Sortable(document.getElementById('list1'), {
      group: 'shared',
      animation: 150
      }),
      new Sortable(document.getElementById('list2'), {
      group: 'shared',
      animation: 150
      }),
      new Sortable(document.getElementById('list3'), {
      group: 'shared',
      animation: 150
      })];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bn3f47g2/1/